# How is a second password better than TAN?

Tags: passwords, tan

Postbank will deactivate two-factor authentication via SMS-TAN in August. You are henceforth to instead provide an authentication password, optionally unlockable via (unspecified) biometry. One password thus authenticates all transactions. Everything is much better and more secure.

Now of course, we may assume that the experts inventing this system are not complete idiots. So obviously there's something that I'm not understanding.

What exactly is the advantage of a password that is indefinitively stored in some form (hopefully hashed in some way) on the server and stored (hopefully encrypted, but necessarily decryptable) on an easily-stolen device over a unique number that is generated on the fly, valid for exactly one given transaction, and expires within five minutes?

Answer (score 1):

If your device is compromised (or “easily stolen”), SMS authentication is just as useless because an attacker can just read the message. The advantage of storing an encrypted password is that it’s hard to access (especially with biometrics), compared to text messages which can by default be read even on a locked screen.

Comment: The "locked screen" part is especially interesting.

Comment: Also, critically, SMS senders can be spoofed.

Comment: Well, the thing with "easily stolen" is that it doesn't matter with SMS. You are only sent an SMS _after_ starting the transaction, and the TAN within is valid only for that transaction, and expires quickly. The stolen phone is worthless otherwise, it would have to be stolen during that one minute, while I'm at home. Not so if my password is stored in there as kinda has to be the case if I can "unlock" transactions with faceid or fingerprint. Plus, it has the app that upon opening lets you start a transaction right away (with account details needed etc).

Comment: @securityOrange: Not an issue. Neither eavesdropping nor spoofing is an issue. The contents of the SMS are worthless as they are valid for an already-defined transaction only. An invalid code does nothing but trigger "Wrong code, please enter again!" in the web form. So eavesdrop and spoof away all you want, it's just worthless.

Comment: @Damon oh yeah, that’s true. Good point. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: @Damon I don't think I quite understand your threat model. If the attacker cannot initiate a transaction with your phone, then it is indeed useless (in both 2FA cases). If they can, then the password is *slightly* more safe as per my answer.

Comment: @apilat: Well, with the new, better mode, the attacker could steal the phone and trick faceid with a photograph (which has been proven to work), which will enable him to both initiate a transaction, and confirm it (the app sends the password upon successful faceid or fingerprint). Or, he could just retrieve the password which is stored in an unspecified (probably insecure) manner in the app. Or, whatever. In the old "inferior" model, he would have to know my login password, start a transaction, _and_ possess my (unlocked) phone.

Comment: No. Encrypting passwords does not provide the level of security you think it does. If the server can decrypt something, then a hacked server can decrypt it just as easily. A server needs to have access to the key at any moment to respond to login attempts. Encryption only obscures data from people that don't know the key. You are not protected from hacks (well, besides extremely limit ones), nor from malicious insiders. Use encryption to enable crypto-shredding, if you want, but until the key is erased "access" is only a little harder than accessing plaintext passwords.

Comment: @Damon In that case I agree that the security is lower. However, this is not because of the change from SMS to password two factor authentication, but rather the fact that it no longer is *two factor*: according to what you're saying, the same password can be used both to start and validate a transaction. If that is not the case and (as you state in your title) this is a second password and a login one is needed too, then my point still stands.

Comment: @FutureSecurity from the point of view of the server - sure. But if you have access to the server, you can initiate any transaction you want anyway. If we look at the client, where it is plausible for the key to not be stored (i.e. derived from biometrics), encryption does give an increase in security.

Comment: You can put an end to transactions. But once information is leaked the damage is done. If you can just dismiss hacks then you're in the same space as people who think storing passwords in plaintext isn't risky. Assuming that software, including access control, is implemented correctly is one premise that does a ton of work toward concluding access is difficult. So much work that any additional layers of security would have no significant advantage.

Comment: Keys are not derived from biometrics. Biometric access control needs to be fault tolerant. Biometric data is not consistent enough to reliably derive keys from. If you add measures to make things more consistent then you don't have enough unpredictable information to derive a strong key. Instead, biometrics use approximate comparisons between sensor data and stored data. If there is a match then the system returns a stored secret key (initially randomly generated). Biometrics isn't something that should be oversold.

Comment: @FutureSecurity I *can* just dismiss **server** hacks, because they are out of scope for this question, which is about 2FA. What you said about biometrics is true: 'derived from biometrics' was shorthand for 'encrypted with the key that can only be obtained from the system if you are able to pass biometrics' (which frankly doesn't add much to the discussion).